# Calling msi file in c from CreateProcess

Tags: c++, c, windows

Is there any option to call msi file from CreateProcess in c language in window OS.

Comment: You can't "call" files in any language. Please clarify what you are asking about.

Comment: I want to invoke the msi file during my program running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows [ShellExecute function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx) will open a file of a registered type with the correct application, which I think is what you are asking about.

Comment: Yes, but if you are doing upgrades of client server software, this is non optimal, since you can't pass flags to it and msiexec /q is probably idea to prevent issues when you are trying to update in the context of a background service.  Even on XP where there is no session isolation you don't want a dialog box with issues popping up waiting for user input, because it is a poor experience, especially in an enterprise environment.  Get the path to msiexe and run it properly.

Answer (score 2):

use [msiexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988(VS.85).aspx) *filename*. ( pass this as a input to Createprocess)

(Refer msiexec for different options)

Comment: @aJ its give me the error. createprocess failed (193). Can you explain little bit more